# In a copper wire, how many electrons does each atom give away?

Tags: electrons, solid-state-physics

As an ion, copper can give off 1, 2, 3 or 4 electrons. But it has 1 s electron in the last shell and 10 d electrons. So as a metal, how many of those are delocalised and free to move around, and how many are staying with the atom?

Comment: This question is better suited for [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/), really, but I think that all the electrons in the outermost shell ($n=4$) are free to move.

Comment: Roughly 1 electron per atom. If I could find a good ref proving that I'd post an answer, but the sites I've seen so far just state it without proof.